# Error: Declared Dependency Missing

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

how to add rosjava_JNI? im installing roboearth and during rosmake...it says cannot find rosjava_JNI...anyone can help?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32336/error:-declared-dependency-missing/) by [ay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2017/ay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2012-04-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you installing on Electric or Fuerte? rosjava_jni has not been released yet for Fuerte, there you need to install from source (repository url: git://code.in.tum.de/git/client-rosjava). In Electric, do:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-electric-client-rosjava-jni
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0